# Finding highest and lowest numbers in list

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
with open('life-expectancy.csv') as file:
    for row in file:
        row = row.strip() #trim
        parts = row.split(',')
        value = float(parts[3])

        max_value = float(-1.0)
        if value > max_value:
            max_value = value

        min_value = float(100.0)
        if value < min_value:
            min_value = value
        # print(sum(value))

print(max_value)
print(min_value)
```

The life expectancy file contains rows that are all like this:

```
Afghanistan,AFG,1981,43.923
```

With different countries, years, etcetera. My goal is to find the highest and lowest life expectancy with the corresponding country and year, but my code is just giving me the life expectancy of the last item in the list (I haven't attempted to add the country and year yet obviously).

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to initialize max and min value outside your loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the  `max_value = float(-1.0)` and `min_value = float(100.0)` above the with statement. This way you reset it on each line.